# Livewire - Missing required parameters for route

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

When livewire is rendering a view, I get an error message:

**Missing required parameters for [Route: book.show]**

But if I just print the value, like `{{ $slug }}` , the view is rendered correctly.

It looks like the model data is not available at render time. Where I am going wrong?

Snippet of my view

```
<a href="{{ route('book.show', $slug) }}">
   Show book
</a>
```

My component

```
class BookForm extends Component
{
    public $slug;
    public $name;
    public $summary;

    protected $listeners = ['fillForm1' => 'editList'];

    public function editList($id)
    {
        $book = Book::find($id);

        $this->slug = $book->slug;
        $this->name = $book->name;
        $this->summary = $book->summary;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.books.book-form');
    }
}
```

My route

```
Route::get('/book/{slug}', 'BookController@show')->name('book.show');
```

My BookController / show method

```
public function show($slug)
{
   ...
}
```

**I'm using "laravel/framework": "^7.0" and "livewire/livewire": "^2.5"**

Comment: Try to use `<a href="{{ route('book.show', [ 'slug' => $slug ]) }}">` instead

Comment: If you print out {{ $slug }} is it correct, if route() is not called with associative array, it take the parameters in order, so it should work, unless your route is nested with another route parameter.

Comment: you should edit your question and add your show function from controller so that we can understand error

Comment: You have a Laravel controller, but showed the code for the Livewire component. There's something missing here -- like that controller code. Keep in mind that the variable in hte `show()` method in your controller should be named `$slug`.

Comment: @DaviMendesDev, I tried to do that, but it didn't work either.

Comment: @Qirel, I'm turning some blade components into livewire components, this code works fine with blade, the problem is that livewire doesn't render with model data. Due to livewire not having the data at render time, route access is happening without the slug parameter.

Comment: @HamzaQureshi, sorry, done!

Comment: there is no code in your controller function it seems that you dont know how laravel works when you hit route first it goes to contoller function then you can call model if reqired but there is nothing in your controller

Comment: can you show me when you emit the fillForm1 event? if the route generates the link before emit the event then $slug not exists. check it.

Answer (score -2):

I think there must be a limitation for livewire not to send the model data when rendering the view. I used the following workaround, if you have a way to improve this please let me know.

```
public function editList($id)
{
   $book = Book::find($id);

   $this->slug = route('book.show', $book->slug);
   $this->name = $book->name;
   $this->summary = $book->summary;
}
```